# Surround outputted email addresses in quotation marks in Python3.2

Tags: python

I have a small script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3.2
#takes the bad_emails out of full_emails and leaves us with good_emails

#This is a manually generated list of bad emails (bounce backs)
bad_list = []
with open("bad_emails.txt","r") as bad:
    for line in bad.readlines():
        bad_list.append(line)
#this is a list of ALL email addresses output by AcyMailing
full_emails = []
with open("full_emails.txt","r") as full:
    for email in full.readlines():
        if email in bad_list:
            pass
        else:
            full_emails.append(email)

#this is a final list containing only the email addresses with want
good_list = []
with open("good_emails","w") as good:
    for email in full_emails:
        good.write(email)
```

What I'm attempting to do is in short: take a list of email addresses from our mailer program called AcyMailing in Joomla and export it out. It has the following format:
    "abc@abc.com"
    "def@def.com"
    "etc@etc.etc"

While my above script works (it gets rid of the 'bad emails' and leaves me with only the 'good emails' I've yet to find a way to make each email surrounded by quotation marks like AcyMailing (Joomla) uses. I've seen that a number of people use regex for such a task. Is that the only way to do this in python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to just wrap the string in quotes:

```
good.write('"' + email.strip() + '"\n')
```

Or you can use `.format`:

```
good.write('"{}"\n'.format(email.strip()))
```

Comment: results in "aaa@aaa.com (then a line break then) ""bbb@bbb.com (repeat) I assume because the element being written already has a new line in it.

Comment: You never stripped the line breaks off of the emails when reading in the first file. Let me edit that into the answer.

Comment: Now I see, thanks Blender for taking the time to answer this.

Answer (score 0):

The for-loops with `.readlines()` are redundant. You could use [`set.difference()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set.difference) to find good e-mails:

```
# read all emails from the file, one email per line, skip blank lines
read_emails = lambda file: (line.strip() for line in file if line.strip())

with open('bad_emails.txt') as bad, open('full_emails.txt') as full:
     good_emails = set(read_emails(full)).difference(read_emails(bad))

with open('good_emails.txt', 'w') as good:
     good.writelines('"%s"\n' % email for email in good_emails)
```